# How do I select a field enclosed within quotes?

Tags: sql, oracle, quote

I'm trying to select a few fields and enclose them within quotes because I have to export these records into a flat file and then insert them into another database. So I'm running these queries on Oracle, and am having trouble trying to add these quotes. This is the query that I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT
  'connection_string' || '|' || 
  ''' || employee_name || '''
FROM
  table1
```

And the output I want is:

```
'connection_string'|'Bob'
'connection_string'|'Jane'
```

I've also tried

```
SELECT
  'connection_string' || '|' || 
  '' || employee_name || ''
FROM
  table1
```

which obviously doesn't work. The connection_string is to be static and stay the same, and the results should be delimited by the pipe

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for the single quotes in the output?  If so:

```
SELECT '''' || 'connection_string' || '''|''' || 
       employee_name || ''''
FROM table1;
```

Two single quotes in a row -- in a string -- represent a single single quote.  Or, in other words, you need four in a row for a string with a single single quote:

```
''''
^ starts the string
-^^ the single quote
---^ ends the string
```

Comment: Hah, that did it. So of the 4 quotes what purpose does the second quote do?

Comment: quuote one says start of a string, quote two is to escape the third quote which is the one you are looking for and the fourth is to end the string.

Comment: @simplycoding  - that did it? On my machine it gives an error message (for an obvious reason:`''''|''''` is incorrect - it produces a string with just one character, a single quote, then the pipe symbol OUTSIDE any quotes, and then another single-character string of a single quote).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? Using the EMP table in the SCOTT schema.

```
select ename, '''connection_string''|''' || ename || ''''
from   scott.emp;

ENAME      '''CONNECTION_STRING''|'''||ENAM
---------- --------------------------------
SMITH      'connection_string'|'SMITH'
ALLEN      'connection_string'|'ALLEN'
WARD       'connection_string'|'WARD'
JONES      'connection_string'|'JONES'
MARTIN     'connection_string'|'MARTIN'
BLAKE      'connection_string'|'BLAKE'
CLARK      'connection_string'|'CLARK'
SCOTT      'connection_string'|'SCOTT'
KING       'connection_string'|'KING'
TURNER     'connection_string'|'TURNER'
ADAMS      'connection_string'|'ADAMS'
JAMES      'connection_string'|'JAMES'
FORD       'connection_string'|'FORD'
MILLER     'connection_string'|'MILLER'
```

Answer (score 0):

Anoter way could be using the [Q syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm):

```
SQL> with tableA(a) as (
  2    select 'aaa' from dual union all
  3    select 'AAA' from dual
  4  )
  5  select q'[Your string ']' || a || q'[']' as A
  6  from tableA;

A
-----------------
Your string 'aaa'
Your string 'AAA'
```

In this case it may be a bit redundant, but it can be useful in more complex situations.

Answer (score 0):

```
select listagg( '''' || TESTNAME || '''',',') from test;
```

This will result the data in
single quotes all the testname seperated by coma and enclosed in single quote